# Extracting row value based on matching columns in separate dataframes using SQL or R

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I have two dataframes as shown below:

Df1

| date | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 | 10 | john |
| 2022-02-30 | 15 | elle |
| 2020-03-04 | 20 | david |

Df2

| date | a |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 | 10 |
| 2022-02-30 | 30 |
| 2020-04-04 | 20 |

I want to extract the values in column b in Dataframe1 only when `Df1$date = Df2$date AND Df1$a = Df2$a`.

In the above example, the only row where both conditions match is row 1, so my output should be

| b |
| --- |
| john |

How can I write this using sqldf in R or even using base R?

Comment: `inner_join(df1, df2)`

Comment: In base R you can use `merge(df1, df2)` or more safely, `merge(df1, df2, by = c("date", "a"))` - If you do `merge(df1, df2)[,3]` it will output  your desired "john"

Comment: I have made sure both my dataframes have the same column names and tried this, but it is showing 0 results even though I manually checked a few entries and there were matches (as in the case above). Any additional thoughts? I'm not sure what the error would be here.

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment, when merging only by the "a" column, the output is fine, but something is not working with the Date column as i can't merge by only the date column either. The date column is listed as a character column, not date, and I'm not sure if that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inner_join` from dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("date", "a")) %>% 
  select(b) # as per @jpsmith comment
     b
1 john
```

Comment: You may want to pipe in a `select(b)` to get the exact desired output from the OP

Comment: I have made sure both my dataframes have the same column names and tried this, but it is showing 0 results even though I manually checked a few entries and there were matches (as in the case above). Any additional thoughts? I'm not sure what the error would be here. I tried the merge comment above, but also had 0 results.

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment, when merging only by the "a" column, the output is fine, but something is not working with the Date column as i can't merge by only the date column either. The date column is listed as a character column, not date, and I'm not sure if that is causing an issue.

Comment: The code by @Jilber Urbina works. I copied the same data in the original dataframes to a new one (with a new variable name) and re-ran the code (now with the new variable names) and it works. There was definitely a problem with the date column in the original dataframe, but I'm not sure why.